# Python subprocess -- close Django server and Docker container with Ctrl-C, return to terminal

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm trying to figure out how to properly close out my script that's supposed to start up a Django server running in a docker container (boot2docker, on Mac OS X). Here's the pertinent code block:

```
try:
    init_code = subprocess.check_output('./initdocker.sh', shell=True)
    subprocess.call('./startdockerdjango.sh', shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    try:
        subprocess.call('./startdockerdjango.sh', shell=True)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return
```

Where `startdockerdjango.sh` takes care of setting the environment variables that docker needs and starts the server up. The script overall is supposed to know whether to do first-time setup and initialization or simply start the container and server; catching the CalledProcessError means that first time setup was already done and that the container and server can just be started up. The startup works fine, but when a user presses Ctrl-C to stop the server, the server stops normally but then apparently the process that started the server is still going. If I press return, then I can go back to the normal terminal command prompt. If I do any sort of shell command, like `ls`, then it will be carried out and then I can return to the terminal. I want to change the code so that, if a user presses Ctrl-C, then the server and the container that the server is running in will stop normally and then, afterward, stop the process and have the whole script exit. How can this be done? I don't want to just kill or terminate the process upon KeyboardInterrupt, since then the server and container won't be able to stop normally but will be killed off abruptly.

**UPDATE:**
I recently tried the following according to Padraic Cunningham's comment:

```
try:
    init_code = subprocess.check_output('./initdocker.sh', shell=True)
    subprocess.call('./startdockerdjango.sh', shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    try:
        startproc = subprocess.Popen('./startdockerdjango.sh')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        startproc.send_signal(SIGTERM)
        startproc.wait()
        return
```

This was my attempt to send a term to the server to shut down gracefully and then use wait() to wait for the process (`startproc`) to complete. This, however, results in just having the container and server end abruptly, something that I was trying to prevent. The same thing happens if I try SIGINT instead. What, if anything, am I doing wrong in this second approach? I still want the same overall thing as before, which is having one single Ctrl-C end the container and server, then exit the script.

Comment: send a signal when you catch the exception

Comment: I'm not very good with the subprocess module, so could you elaborate? How exactly would I be able to send a signal when catching the exception such that the script will exit after the user presses Ctrl-C to stop the server?

Comment: You can send any signal you wish, once you catch the exception send a term to the server to shutdown gracefully, use popen instead of call and call p.wait to wait for the process to complete but you may want to have a time limit in case your server does not shutdown after you send the signal

Comment: Either I'm doing it wrong or what you said doesn't work in my situation. See my update edit for details. Having the container and server abruptly stop is not ideal since then the next attempt to run the script will result in a non-zero exit when trying to start up the server and container.

Comment: You have to handle how the server shuts down when it receives the signal, what do you want to happen?

Comment: What I want to happen is, rather than terminate what seems to be the parent process (the Python script) and thus abruptly terminate the docker container process, I want the one SIGINT to first gracefully shut down the server and container, then exit the script. Apologies for having such a hard time with this, a lot of this stuff is new to me. The different things I'm trying keep abruptly terminating the parent process, it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it wasn't worth the effort to have the script know to either do first-time initialization or server+container startup. Instead, the script will just try first-time setup and then will tell the user to do `docker-compose up` after successful setup. This is a better solution for my specific situation than trying to figure out how to have Ctrl-C properly shut down the server and then exit the script.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create the process using `Popen`. It will give you a  little more control on how you manage the child process.

```
env = {"MY_ENV_VAR": "some value"}
proc = subprocess.Popen("./dockerdjango.sh", env=env)
try:
    proc.wait()
except KeyboardInterupt:
    proc.terminate() # on linux this gives the a chance to clean up,
    # or even ignore the signal entirely
    # use proc.send_signal(...) and the module signal to send other signals.
    # or proc.kill() if you wish to be kill the process immediately.
```

If you set the environment variables in python it will also result in less child processes that need to be killed.

Comment: The problem with that is that terminating the process will prevent the server and container from stopping normally, which is something I pointed out in my original question.

Comment: on linux `terminate` sends `SIGTERM`, processes are free to do whatever they wish with a `SIGTERM`, including ignoring it. Most will take it as a signal to do cleanup and exit.

Answer (score 0):

To Reset django server subprocess execute in your terminal:

```
$ sudo lsof -i tcp:8080
$ sudo lsof -i tcp:8080|awk '{print $2}'|cut -d/ -f 1|xargs kill
```